# next-i18next detect locale with querystring

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

This is my next-i18next.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['ko', 'en', 'ja', 'zh'],
  },
  detection: {
    order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage'],
    lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
  },
};
```

I want to detect locale from querystring. ([www.example.com/detail?lang=en](http://www.example.com/detail?lang=en)) But it does not work. next-i18next.config.js is already active in my project but app detect only with path([www.example.com/en/detail](http://www.example.com/en/detail)) What is missing for my config file?

#### use

- next : 12.1.6
- next-i18next : 12.0.0
- react : 18.2.0

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? You've set `lookupQuerystring` to `lng` and you have `lang` in your example url

Comment: @L.Letovanec oh, yes. It's just a typo and it doesn't matter with my problem.

Comment: if you use i18n functionality of next.js you can’t create your own detection. Here an alternative: https://locize.com/blog/next-i18n-static/ -> https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples/ssg